# How to display an image with a dynamic name in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, png

I have

```
name.of.image<-paste(x, ".png", sep="")
```

I would like to display this image in a Rmarkdown (output PDF) as

```
![](`r message(op.png)`){width=25%}
```

however this does not seem to work.

```
![]('r sprintf("%s.png", x)'){width=25%}
```

does not work either.

How can I properly display this image?

Answer (score 0):

Always try to make your code more laconic:

````
```{r}
x <- "my_image"
```

\centering
![](`r paste(x, ".png", sep="")`){width=25%}
````

but this

```
![](`r sprintf("%s.png", x)`){width=25%}
```

is also work (don't mess ` with ')